# RVM installed ruby no such file or directory

Tags: ruby, rvm, ubuntu-12.04

I have installed `RVM` without any problems. But when I try to install `ruby 1.9.3` it returns an error:

```
ruby-1.9.3-p392 - #configure  
ruby-1.9.3-p392 - #download  
ruby-1.9.3-p392 - #validate archive  
ruby-1.9.3-p392 - #extract  
ruby-1.9.3-p392 - #validate binary  
ruby-1.9.3-p392 - #setup  
/usr/local/rvm/scripts/functions/utility: line 708: /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby: No such file or directory  
/usr/local/rvm/scripts/functions/utility: line 713: /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby: No such file or directory  
ln: target `/gems/' is not a directory: No such file or directory  
Saving wrappers to '/usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.3-p392'........  
ruby-1.9.3-p392 - #importing default gemsets, this may take time...............................  
Making gemset ruby-1.9.3-p392 pristine.....  
Making gemset ruby-1.9.3-p392@global pristine.....  
brian@vs3594:~$ rvm use --default 1.9.3  
Using /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392  
brian@vs3594:~$ rvm use 1.9.3  
Using /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392  
brian@vs3594:~$ ruby -v  
-bash: /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby: No such file or directory  
brian@vs3594:~$ rvm use system  
Now using system ruby.  
brian@vs3594:~$ ruby -v  
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [i686-linux]
```

I am lost with this. Any help is appreciated!

Using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 32bit clean install

Comment: I think the problem is you apt-get installed ruby.  This messes everything up because rvm doesn't handle system ruby well. It likes to have rubies in ~/.rvm.

Comment: you might need to install some OS dependencies? - try running `rvm notes` and see if it lists ubuntu packages you need to install?

Comment: For a complete guide check out https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-precise-pangolin-with-rvm

Comment: RVM bugs should be reported to https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/ - make sure to use `rvm get head` before reporting.

Comment: Thanks for all your answers! I reinstalled ubuntu 12.04 and removed all syste rubies. Reinstalled curl and rvm including a ruby as root without the sudo command. Works perfect now!

Comment: Please list what you did as an Answer and then accept it.  That way, it might help someone else and will no longer show up in the 'Unanswered' section.

Answer (score -1):

> /usr/local/rvm/scripts/functions/utility

You installed RVM using a universal, multi-user, installation which is not recommended unless you are supporting a shared host. For the majority of uses you should use the single-user installation which will put RVM in ~/.rvm, along with all the Rubyies and gems associated with them. By installing in /usr/local every action needed to modify or install a new Ruby will involve using escalated privileges.

When installing RVM, it's important to read, understand, and follow the [installation directions on the RVM site](http://rvm.io/rvm/install), not directions you'd find on other sites which might, or might not, pertain to your exact situation or which might have become stale. In [RVM's installation page](http://rvm.io/rvm/install), the authors specifically say:

> External tutorials
>
> Note that that any outside tutorials are NOT supported whether they work or not. Tutorials are great, however we have spent massive amounts of man hours debugging the installation process. Please use the install process(es) from this site only, as this is the only supported installation types and methods.

RVM is a powerful tool, which has evolved greatly since it was first introduced, and the authors of RVM are the best sources for how to install it.

People who wrote pages about how to install it a couple years ago might have been accurate then, but all bets are off about their accuracy several years later.